# How do you add multiple HBox?

Tags: java, javafx

I have recently started using JavaFX but I am having trouble with this.

My task is to create a GUI application that displays the assessment value and property tax when a user enters the actual value of a property with a JavaFX user interface.

But for some reason, it doesn't work the way I wanted to. When I type in the objects to the scene section, it prints out:

"java: incompatible types: javafx.scene.layout.HBox cannot be converted to double"

How do I display multiple HBox in one scene?

**Instruction for this Section**

Write the code that instantiates the control for the actual value. Then, write the code that creates an HBox layout container, and place the control that you created inside
the HBox. You should have 10 pixels of spacing between the controls in the HBox. Set
the HBox container's alignment to center.
Write the code that instantiates the controls for the assessment value output label.
Then, write the code that creates an HBox layout container, and place the control that
you created inside the HBox. Set the HBox container's alignment to center left.
Write the code that instantiates the controls for the property tax output label. Then,
write the code that creates an HBox layout container, and place the control that you
created inside the HBox. Set the HBox container's alignment to center left.
Write the code that instantiates the controls for the calcButton control. Then, write
the code that creates an HBox layout container, and place the controls that you
created inside the HBox. Set the HBox container's alignment to center.

[image]

**My Code**(Please ignore the button section, I haven't done it yet)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PropertyTax2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Label actualValue1 = new Label("Actual Value:");
        TextField input = new TextField();

        HBox actualValue2 = new HBox(10);
        actualValue2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        actualValue2.getChildren().addAll(actualValue1, input);

        Label assessmentValue1 = new Label("Assessment value:");
        Label propertyTax1 = new Label("Property tax:");

        HBox assessmentValue2 = new HBox();
        assessmentValue2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        assessmentValue2.getChildren().addAll(assessmentValue1);

        HBox propertyTax2 = new HBox();
        propertyTax2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        propertyTax2.getChildren().addAll(propertyTax1);


        Scene scene = new Scene(actualValue2, assessmentValue2, propertyTax2);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch();}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Scene scene = new Scene(actualValue2, assessmentValue2, propertyTax2);
```

With

```
VBox root = new VBox(actualValue2, assessmentValue2, propertyTax2);
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

The reason you are getting `java: incompatible types: javafx.scene.layout.HBox cannot be converted to double` is because one of the constructors for `Scene` is `Scene​(Parent root, double width, double height)`. So after the root node, the other two variables should be doubles. You attempted to pass more nodes.

**Note:** I would recommend renaming your parent nodes. I would also recommend that you do a few tutorials to learn when and how to use parent nodes. This solution is not a good one.

I personally like to use a prefix that lets me know what kind of node the variable is. Example `HBox hBoxPropertyTax = new HBox()` or `Label lblPropertyTax = new Label("Hello!")`